# PHP Session with cURL

Tags: php

I've developed an API function with php to make a user login from siteA to siteB.
siteA-login.php

```
$url = "https://api.siteb.com/login";
$cookie = "cookie-api.txt";
$curl = curl_init();
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
//curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, "data=".json_encode($curlPost));
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt ($curl, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 1);
curl_setopt ($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt ($curl, CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR, $cookie);
curl_setopt ($curl, CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE, $cookie);
curl_setopt ($curl, CURLOPT_REFERER, $url);
$response = (curl_exec($curl));
curl_close($curl);

header("location: https://siteb.com/restricted-content");
```

This is siteb where I login the user with CI4:

```
$session = session();
$session->set(array('user'=>$user));
```

However after the redirect I go to login page and not in the restricted content.
How can I solve?

Comment: The cookie in the cURL call is owned by PHP, which is on your server. This is different from the cookie, needed by your browser to get access to the web site, which is stored on the computer where the browser client runs. Two different cookies.

Comment: Ok so cookies it's not a solution in this case? Are there other solution we can try? I thought about a link with a special parameter to make user login when he visit it by the redirect

Comment: See answer by Codewriter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can't set Cookies for other domain as you are on.

maybe you can try something like this:

- User try to login
- API request from A to B to get a Key ( remembered in Database Site B )
- Redirect User with this Key to Site B ( query in Database if key correct )
- Login User, delete Key to prevent second usage

Comment: It's a good idea...I what I thought when I answered to KIKO Software :)